# Detected Dependencies - Where is each dependency coming from?

Tags: visual-studio, installation

I have two detected dependencies with the same name (different paths) showing up in my setup project's detected dependencies. One's the "old" one, at an old path. How can i determine which portion of my primary project is causing the "old" one to show up? I can probably do it by trial and error, but is there a quick/direct way?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) you can right-click on the dependency and ask for the depenent code fragments.
Otherwise I would remove the dependency and look where the compiler gets errors.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the easiest way was to right click on each potential parent (only about half a dozen) and choose Dependencies ... working through them till I found the culprit.